# Retrieving Local Files Flash Player 9

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've recently encountered a problem whilst coding when trying to upload local files to flash. With Flash Player 10 you can use the following code to load local files into flash.

```
FileReference.load();
```

This is not available in Flash Player 9 which is causing me issues as I only have a copy of CS3. All I need to do is retrieve a local jpg from the users computer and temporarily display it in my flash application. So to clarify, uploading to the server isn't required unless this is the only way to do this with Flash Player 9?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `load()` method in the Flash Player 9 version of the `FileReference` class and you have to `upload()` it to server and read it from there. No other way.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you need to upload it to the server when using Flash Player 9. Access to the local files was one of the most anticipated features of Flash 10.

Comment: That is very sad indeed. Thanks for your reply.